# How include c++ binary in gstreamer plugin?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I'm trying to develop a gstreamer plugin that includes KODO linear network coding. Kodo comes as a binary file c++. At the time of creating and filling with autogen.sh make and sudo make install does not detect any error. When I run gst-inspect mykodoenc the result is:

> GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin
>   '/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmykodoenc.so':
>   /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmykodoenc.so: undefined symbol:
>   _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE

How can include c++ binary module on my gstreamer plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When running gst-inspect the binary is not able to find c++ symbols needed during runtime, so you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to libstdc++ shared library.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libstdc++.so.6
```

Also the libstdc++ version should be same as the one expected by kodo binary file you mentioned. You can check it by using

```
ldd <kodo_binary>
```

Also to check other missing dependencies please use

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmykodoenc.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding -lstdc++ in the correct place in the makefile.

```
libgstmykododec_la_SOURCES = gstmykododec.c gstmykododec.h kodoc.h
```

libgstmykododec_la_CFLAGS = $(GST_CFLAGS) -I./kodolib/include

libgstmykododec_la_LIBADD = $(GST_LIBS)  -L./kodolib  -lkodoc_static -lfifi -lcpuid -lstdc++

libgstmykododec_la_LDFLAGS = $(GST_PLUGIN_LDFLAGS)  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm

libgstmykododec_la_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=disable-static